# How to integrate over rows with Spark and Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd, integral

I'm currently trying to write a Spark job in Java that calculates the integral of a column in the data set.

The data looks like this:

```
    DateTime                velocity (in km/h)        vehicle 
    2016-03-28 11:00:45     80                        A
    2016-03-28 11:00:45     75                        A
    2016-03-28 11:00:46     70                        A
    2016-03-28 11:00:47     68                        A
    2016-03-28 11:00:48     72                        A
    2016-03-28 11:00:48     75                        A
    ... 
    2016-03-28 11:00:47     68                        B
    2016-03-28 11:00:48     72                        B
    2016-03-28 11:00:48     75                        B
```

To calculate the distance (in km) for each line, I have to define the time difference between the current and the next line and multiply it with the speed.
Then the result must be added to the result of the previous row to retrieve the "total distance" driven at that moment.

I now came up with something like this. But it'll compute one vehicle per map job and there could be millions of records....

```
    final JavaRDD<String[]> input = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(
                new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "80", "VIN1"},
                new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "60", "VIN1"},
                new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "50", "VIN1"},
                new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:01", "80", "VIN1"},
                new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:05", "80", "VIN1"},
                new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:09", "80", "VIN1"},
                new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "80", "VIN2"},
                new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:01", "80", "VIN2"}
        ));

        // grouping by vehicle and date:
        final JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String[]>> byVinAndDate = input.groupBy(new Function<String[], String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(String[] record) throws Exception {
                return record[0] + record[3]; // date, vin
            }
        });

        // mapping each "value" (all record matching key) to result
        final JavaRDD<String[]> result = byVinAndDate.mapValues(new Function<Iterable<String[]>, String[]>() {
            @Override
            public String[] call(Iterable<String[]> records) throws Exception {
                final Iterator<String[]> iterator = records.iterator();

                String[] previousRecord = iterator.next();

                for (String[] record : records) {

                     // Calculate difference current <-> previous record
                     // Add result to new list

                    previousRecord = record;
                }

                return new String[]{
                        previousRecord[0],
                        previousRecord[1],
                        previousRecord[2],
                        previousRecord[3],
                        NewList.get(previousRecord[0]+previousRecord[1]+previousRecord[2]+previousRecord[2])

                };
            }
        }).values();
```

I'm totally lost on how to translate this problem to map/reduce transformations, without losing the benefit of distributed computing.

I know it's against the nature of MR and Spark but any suggestions on how to interlink data rows or solve this in an elegant way would be really helpful :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you do it right and you shouldn't afraid of millions records:

- apache spark would do a great job to balance it, one worker might be busy with long task while one another would process few shorter,
- if you could parse time and distance, then you might end up with double or even integers and looping through a few millions of doubles doesn't cost too much to worry about it.
- in the given input shouldn't be millions of records, because there are only 1440 minutes in a day.

Although your approach doesn't require any additional memory to calculate, I propose another approach - to use aggregateByKey and first combine all of times and distances into an arrays per each key (vin, date). 
I'm sorry for the example, it's java 8.

```
    final JavaRDD<String[]> input = jsc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "80", "VIN1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "60", "VIN1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "50", "VIN1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:01", "80", "VIN1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:05", "80", "VIN1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:09", "80", "VIN1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "80", "VIN2"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:01", "80", "VIN2"}
    ));

    input
            .mapToPair(v -> new Tuple2<>(v[0] + v[3], new Tuple2<>(v[1], v[2])))
            .aggregateByKey(
                    new Tuple2<>(new ArrayList<>(N), new ArrayList<>(N)),
                    (Tuple2<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> t, Tuple2<String, String> v) -> { //function to add new values to the collection
                        t._1().add(v._1());
                        t._2().add(v._2());
                        return t;
                    },
                    (Tuple2<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> t1, Tuple2<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> t2) -> { //function to combine collections
                        t1._1().addAll(t2._1());
                        t1._2().addAll(t2._2());
                        return t1;
                    })
            .foreach(v -> { //prints
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(v);
            });
```

This code gives me the following

```
(2016-03-28VIN2,([11:00, 11:01],[80, 80]))
(2016-03-28VIN1,([11:00, 11:00, 11:00, 11:01, 11:05, 11:09],[80, 60, 50, 80, 80, 80]))
```

Instead of printing in foreach you have to use `mapValues` to loop over two arrays at the same to get differences and multiplications with distance and then use `reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b)` to get the sum.

To save some memory and create less number of ArrayLists, you can do create them big enough at the beginning - first line of aggregateByKey - instead of N provide smth like 1000000, f.e.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather translate the problem into dataframe API, using spark, letting spark to manage map/reduce (avoiding iterators and arrays). Practically we want to computed the distance for each vechile/per period of time. So this are the steps that I used:

- Convert RDD to dataframe

> ```
> case class Vechicle(data: String, time: String, velocity: Int, id: String)
>     val df = sc.parallelize(List(
>         Vechicle("2016-03-28", "11:00", 80, "VIN1"),
>         Vechicle("2016-03-28", "11:00", 60, "VIN1"),
>         Vechicle("2016-03-28", "11:00", 50, "VIN1"),
>         Vechicle("2016-03-28", "11:01", 80, "VIN1"),
>         Vechicle("2016-03-28", "11:05", 80, "VIN1"),
>         Vechicle("2016-03-28", "11:09", 80, "VIN1"),
>         Vechicle("2016-03-28", "11:00", 80, "VIN2"),
>         Vechicle("2016-03-28", "11:01", 80, "VIN2")
>       )).toDF()
> ```

- because some data is pushed for the same time (minutes:seconds) compute the average on this (use seconds as a unit of measure)

> val velocities = df.groupBy(df("data"), df("id"),
>   df("time")).agg((avg("velocity") / 3600).as("avg_velocity"))

It will give the following output:

`+----------+----+-----+--------------------+----+
|      data|  id| time|        avg_velocity|rank|
+----------+----+-----+--------------------+----+
|2016-03-28|VIN1|11:00|0.017592592592592594|   1|
|2016-03-28|VIN1|11:01|0.022222222222222223|   2|
|2016-03-28|VIN1|11:05|0.022222222222222223|   3|
|2016-03-28|VIN1|11:09|0.022222222222222223|   4|
|2016-03-28|VIN2|11:00|0.022222222222222223|   1|
|2016-03-28|VIN2|11:01|0.022222222222222223|   2|
+----------+----+-----+--------------------+----+`

- Using dataframe analytics API compute a time frame, based on a partitioning over *data* and *id* columns, retaining the number of seconds between these time frames

> ```
>       val velocities = df.groupBy(df("data"), df("id"), df("time")).agg((avg("velocity") / 3600).as("avg_velocity"))
>   val overDataAndId = Window.partitionBy(df("data"), df("id")).orderBy(df("time"))
>
>   val rank = denseRank.over(overDataAndId)
>   val nextTime = lead(df("time"), 1).over(overDataAndId)
>
>   val secondsBetween = udf((start: String, end: String) => {
>     val sStart = time.LocalTime.parse(start)
>     val sEnd = end match {
>       case null => sStart
>       case t: String if t.isEmpty => sStart
>       case t: String if t.equalsIgnoreCase("null") => sStart
>       case t: String => time.LocalTime.parse(end)
>     }
>     Seconds.secondsBetween(sStart, sEnd).getSeconds
>   })
>
>
>   velocities.withColumn("rank", rank).show()
>   velocities.withColumn("nextTime", nextTime).show()
>
>   val seconds = velocities.withColumn("seconds", secondsBetween(df("time"), nextTime))
>   seconds.show()
> ```

It will ouput :

`+----------+----+-----+--------------------+-------+
|      data|  id| time|        avg_velocity|seconds|
+----------+----+-----+--------------------+-------+
|2016-03-28|VIN1|11:00|0.017592592592592594|     60|
|2016-03-28|VIN1|11:01|0.022222222222222223|    240|
|2016-03-28|VIN1|11:05|0.022222222222222223|    240|
|2016-03-28|VIN1|11:09|0.022222222222222223|      0|
|2016-03-28|VIN2|11:00|0.022222222222222223|     60|
|2016-03-28|VIN2|11:01|0.022222222222222223|      0|
+----------+----+-----+--------------------+-------+`

- Compute a cumulative sum over the distance

> ```
>     val distance = seconds.withColumn("distance", seconds("avg_velocity") * seconds("seconds"))
>   distance.show()
>   val cumulativeDistance = sum(distance("distance")).over(overDataAndId)
>
>   val all = distance.withColumn("cum_distance", cumulativeDistance)
>   all.show()
> ```

It will output the cumulative distance(lines with seconds == 0 are the one with total distance per vechile id per time). After dropping some columns it will show :

`+----------+----+------------------+
|      data|  id|      cum_distance|
+----------+----+------------------+
|2016-03-28|VIN1|11.722222222222223|
|2016-03-28|VIN2|1.3333333333333335|
+----------+----+------------------+`

I find it as a solution that is more readable and that let spark manage operation on dataframes. Code is written in scala but can be translated in java very easy.